# Why is setTimeout executing timeExpired with no delay?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am learning javascript, and have come across a problem that leaves me completely stumped.  When I call setTimeout the function parameter runs immediately with no delay.

Overall program (segment) purpose: User inputs a number of minutes they want to set a timer for.  Inputed value is passed to a submitName(), which sets the timer and calls timeExpired() when the timer goes off.

Relevant HTML:

```
<form id="frm1">
Name: <input type="number" id="fname" name="fname"
step="1" min="1" max="1500" value="1"><br>
</form> 

<p>How many minutes do you want to set the alarm for?</p>

<button id="submit" onclick="submitName();">Submit</button>
```

Relevnt Javascript:

```
<script>


function timeExpired()
{
  document.write("Timer off!");
}

function submitName() {
  var x = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var num = x*60000;

  document.write("<p id='time'>Timer set for: " + x + " minutes.</p>" 
  + "<link rel='stylesheet' href='colours.css'/>");

  setTimeout(function(){timeExpired();},num);
}

</script>
```

What I've tried:

√ Comparing examples on MDN, W3schools, and other questions on stack overflow to try to find a solution.

√ Wrapping in anonymous function (as above).  Many variations with and without anonymous function adding/removing the brackets() and semi-colon();  of timeExpired on function call.

√ Debugging with the built in firefox debugger (no errors found).

√ Checking the value submitted by the user is properly assigned to x, and multiple assigned to num.

NOTES:

-I am aware of the dubious reputation of W3schools, and am keeping my eyes open.

-I am aware that document.write() overwrites the contents of the fully-loaded screen.  I am only using it in a limited capacity in (user-invoked) pop-up windows.

Comment: It's working fine http://jsbin.com/likilaxiwe/1/edit?html,js,console,output I could see the delay

Comment: dubious reputation of w3schools, lol

Comment: Thanks, I've checked the js bin and on my system the submitName document.write in the js bin shows up, but timeExpired one never excutes.

Comment: Can you try using an alert in timeExpired(), or some other mechanism such setting the text in a div or span already on the page? I wonder if it's failing to get written to the correct place for some scoping reason e.g. because it's being executed from a different thread.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried an alert() in timeExpired before and it didn't work.  But I will take another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having tried it, I suppose that `document.write()` replaces the entire document including the script tag that contains your JavaScript functions. As an effect, the function cannot be executed anymore.

Could you try to replace only the content of an element contained in the body, next to the script tag? For example:

`<body>
  <div id="content">
    <form ...
    <button ...
  </div>
  <script>
  ...
  </script>
</body>`

Comment: I just re-tried the alert() in setTimeout with the same result.  I will try to replace my document.write statements with innerHTML or something else, to see if it works.